# SharePoint Modern List - Change fill color of column headers

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

I have a Modern SP list, and the client wants the column headers to be highlighted in yellow, or have a fill color of yellow.

Does anyone know of the JSON I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using SharePoint JSON formatting. This is a known limitation of JSON formatting in SharePoint.

You cannot only format the column headers using JSON formatting in SharePoint online.

**Documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

---

You have to format the list view from scratch and build custom headers using JSON. But, it will remove all SharePoint OOTB functionalities.

[image]

**Reference sample**: [Custom Header](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/custom-header)