# SharePoint Online: JSON - Add red dotted line under each list row

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I am trying to format a list view with JSON. I want to place a thin red dotted line under each row using `"border-bottom": "1px dotted red"`.

I think I have far to go in understanding the JSON structure so I'm hoping someone can start this off and I can build on it.

Comment: Are you trying to do it in normal list view or in gallery/tiles view? You want red dotted line only or you are fine with other color as well if possible to achieve easily?

Comment: I am looking for a red dotted line in a normal (modern) list view

Comment: Ok, I tried to answer what are the possible ways using JSON formatting. check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `additionalRowClass` property and specify the `ms-borderColor-red` and `sp-field-borderBottomDotted` classes using this view format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "ms-borderColor-red sp-field-borderBottomDotted"
}
```

You can find more details about what border classes are available here:

- [ms-borderColor-*](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/groupings/classes/ms-borderColor/)
- [sp-css-borderColor-*](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/groupings/classes/sp-css-borderColor/)
- [sp-css-border Other](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/groupings/classes/sp-css-border/)
- [sp-field-border*](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/groupings/classes/sp-field-border/)

Comment: Thank you both!!! This is exactly what I needed!
More so, I need to become more comfortable using JSON instead of CSS and jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for answer Chris. How could I forget to look at the PnP samples site for the supported classes :(

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to find any predefined classes which are supported in SharePoint JSON formatting for your requirements.

For list/table view you can use `additionalRowClass` to apply additional classes without loosing list/table view and SharePoint default functionalities like context menu.

**For example** (I found these classes only to apply border to list/table view)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "dropHintlineBottom"
}
```

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "sp-field-borderTopBottomDotted"
}
```

[image]

You can find supported predefined classes at:

1. [Predefined classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#predefined-classes) - Microsoft official documentation
2. [SharePoint Online CSS Classes](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/) - list of classes collected by Denis Molodtsov - few classes like `sp-field-borderBottomDotted` did not work for me.

---

Possible solutions you can try:

1. Find predefined class which meets your requirements and use in above JSON
2. Format complete view using JSON to create custom list/table view as shown [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303892/sharepoint-modern-list-change-fill-color-of-column-headers/303893#303893) - it will remove all SharePoint OOTB functionalities.
3. Create custom CSS class with required CSS, [add it to all modern pages using SPFx application customizer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353) and then use that class in your JSON